# Need some assistance with redirects in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My problem is that both non-HTTPS requests and requests with WWW redirects to Main_Page, which is fine when the requested url is the root domain, but not if the request is an article, special page etc.

**Example 1:** http:// example.com/wiki/Articlename redirects to https:// example.com/wiki/Main_Page, but I want to redirect to https:// example.com/wiki/Articlename

**Example 2:** https:// www.example.com/wiki/Articlename redirects to https:// example.com/wiki/Main_Page, but I want to redirect to https:// example.com/wiki/Articlename

This is my settings in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Force HTTP to HTTPS/SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Redirect Example.com to Example.com/wiki/Main_Page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wiki/$1 [PT,L]

# Short url for wiki pages
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [PT,L]

# Permanent redirect www url to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Using MediaWiki on a shared host (Debian 8 Jessie, Apache, PHP 5.6), so httpd.conf is not an option. Example.com only serves MediaWiki and that is why the domain is redirected to https:// example.com/wiki/Main_Page (default).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: HTTPS rewrite is now working after moving "# Force HTTP to HTTPS/SSL" to the top in .htaccess, but WWW-rewrite still does not work. Code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem lies with your use of 'L' after RewriteRule - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

it causes rule processing to cease, while it seems your logic requires several rules to execute